# Have to click 2 times before it opens my component

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, google-maps-markers

GM,
I am a beginner in Angular, i use Leaflet for my application.
I created some markers, and i want to open another component when i click on the marker.

This is the marker click

```
marker.on('click', () => {
  this.isAnySelectedObject = true;
});
```

Then in the app.js , under the map div, i put a ngIf on my child component

```
<marker-infos *ngIf="isAnySelectedObject"></marker-infos>
```

I have to click 2 times before the component appears, can someone help me please?

Comment: Can you share in your question your component.ts code? Maybe you have to use ChangeDetection. When you created your component you set ChangeDetection to "onPush"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :

import the ChangeDetectorRef and everytime i call a component in my map i only have to call this function "this.changeDetector.detectChanges();"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

put this code  in ngOnInit():

```
marker.on('click', () => {
  this.isAnySelectedObject = true;
});
```